# input_shape error in first dense layer of tensoflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to create a model which takes a python list of 4 elements and returns two values as a prediction. Here is my code:

```
class DQNagent:

    def create_model(self):

        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation ='relu',input_shape =(4,1)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation ='relu'))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="linear"))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])               
        return model

    def model_summary(self,model):
        return model.summary()

    def predict(self, state):
        return model.predict(state)

state = [ 0.02495595  0.04527366 -0.002845  0.04326009]
agent = DQNagent()
model = agent.create_model()
action = model.predict(state)
print(action)
```

This code is raising an error as:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

I have given the `input_shape=(4,1)`. Is this the wrong way I am giving the `input_shape`?
How can I fix this error?

When I am giving the input_shape = (1,4), it still throwing the same error. Why is it so happening? I have only one `state` example to feed it and I want only two numbers as output.
Is it possible?
Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.predict(X)` expects batch to be the first dimension of `X`. In your case it interprets your 4x1 array like you provided a batch of 4 examples of size 1. Add a new dimension to state for it to become 1x4 so it's a batch of 1, that contains 4 features.

```
class DQNagent:

    def create_model(self):

        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation ='relu',input_shape=(4, )))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation ='relu'))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="linear"))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])               
        return model

    def model_summary(self,model):
        return model.summary()

    def predict(self, state):
        return model.predict(state)

state = [[ 0.02495595,  0.04527366, -0.002845,  0.04326009]]
agent = DQNagent()
model = agent.create_model()
action = model.predict(state)
print(action)
```

Comment: then the input shape should be like  (1,). Am I correct? Why you have put 8 units in the last dense layer? I just need the output shape to be [a,b] like. Could you please clarify it?

Comment: @UjjawalM. You can set your input shape as you wish. I tested the code above and it works with latest version of tensorflow

Comment: I have updated my comment, could you please recheck it?

Comment: I just used that for test purposes, that 8 is selected completely random, in your case it should be size of the action space, you can use your desired output shape. What is a and b in your case?

Comment: [a,b] = list of two elements. Even if I replace 8 with 2, I am getting (4,2) shape output but I want (1,2) output.